# Understanding Dinic's algorithm using dynamic trees

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, network-flow

I have here a directed graph that I used to perform [Dinic's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm) to find maximum flow. I need to adjust this graph and this algorithm to work with dynamic trees (i.e. the Sleator-Tarjan algorithm).

I just wish I could find an image source or video that can help me visualize the steps. Something [like this](http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~jst//cse/542/text/sec19.pdf) is really close. But I just really want to find thing to lead me step by step in a visual way or a way that doesn't involve pseudocode.

Comment: Being able to understand an algorithm from its general description (i.e. some code) is a central part of algorithmics. I'm afraid there is no shortcut; most clear examples are bound to miss cases. I suggest you 1) look at the reasoning for correctness (that proof is bound to contain essential information) and 2) build your own examples with some inputs, the code and a stack of paper.